# iOS Change current language on the fly for both localizable.string and storyboard.strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, storyboard

I want to change my apps language on the fly. For Localizable.strings it works well, because they will get set in code.

But for storyboard.string it doesn't work. The app needs to get restarted. There are some threads about this subject, I reviewed nearly all of them but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer for me.

I do not want to set every string in code by connecting outlets it's a meaningless effort in my opinion. If I don't have any option I will do it. The app should choose correct storyboard.strings file.

This how my storyboard.strings and localizable.strings look

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thnx already.

Answer (score -1):

I found bet solution for me:

1 - First of all you should create different storyboard for different language.
E.g. Main_iPhone-ru.storyboard, Main_iPhone-en.storyboard, ....

2 - Then create manager to store current bundle and storyboard

3 - Create method (e.g. [changeLanguageTo:@"en"]) and in this method add next:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj"]; // e.g. lang = en

if (path == nil) {
    bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
} else {
    bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
}

NSString *storyBoard = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? @"Main_iPhone" : @"Main_iPad";
storyBoard = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", storyBoard, lang]; // e.g. storyBoard = Main_iPhone-en
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoard bundle:bundle]; // is localized storyboard
```

After you get self.storyboard.

```
UIViewController *rootStoryboardController = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[window setRootViewController:rootStoryboardController]; // window is UIWindow from AppDelegate
```

Move to current visible controller

Comment: I've thought about that solution before and I think it is not a proper solution. If there is a change in storyboard, all of the storyboard should be changed. I've connected all `iboutlet`'s to variables. So I can change the strings on the fly by code with localizable strings.

Comment: Hm, but when you have a lot of iboutlets - are you sure that this is better solutions ?
You need to add string in two or more files anyway

Comment: Strings will come localizable string file so there will be one identifier and its translations. For me it's more reasonable to work with iboutlet connection rather than multiple storyboards. Also even storyboards have their localizable version which you can write strings in it to deal with translation without creating new storyboards.